# How can I start image processing using EMGU?

Tags: emgucv

I am totally new to programming using emgu.I recently understood that it would be helpful to use this library for image processing.So I need to have a good text or ebook which can help me to get familiar with different functions and structures.I would be thankful if you name the best of them and tell me where I can download them.

Answer (score 1):

In this [link](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/Index.html) you can study the emgu cv api and find all methods description and documentation.

You can also check the Open CV [ebook](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/vision/dipakmj/papers/OReilly%20Learning%20OpenCV.pdf) and this [one](http://docs.opencv.org/opencv_tutorials.pdf) with tutorials.

The good thing about Emgu CV is that you can call Open CV methods directly throw the CvInvoke Class

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net (which you probably are) start by [Aforge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/) an easier library to use with lots of good articles.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [site](http://fewtutorials.bravesites.com/tutorials), I think it contains good start for learning emgu cv

Answer (score 0):

It really depends if you have any objectives, previous knowledge of Image Processing/Pattern recognition, OpenCV, knowledge of OO Programming...

If you have a clear objective, and some previous knowledge, a good start is to think about what exactly you want to do, find how to do it on OpenCV, and port it to EMGU, first using CvInvoke, then using the EMGU classes and using the [EMGU documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/Index.html) to help you. Then, if you have specific questions, you can search or ask them here.

If you don't know OpenCV or Image Processing/Pattern recognition, I would recommend you to start with them (if you want to learn it on C#, use EMGU with CvInvoke).

Answer (score 0):

you can try emcu.cv.examples and read these codes, try, finally you should write different codes using these examples